# Is there a tool to reorganize React components?

Tags: reactjs, import, automation

Is there a tool or a feature built into a common code editor/IDE that makes it easy to reorganize React components?  I want change my folder structure and have all import statements automatically update.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are more `most used` ides for JavaScript/React

- https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/
- https://code.visualstudio.com/
- https://atom.io

I personally used `WebStorm` which offers nice feature called `refactor/move` https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/move-refactorings.html when you move any file/folder it can automatically find all references and replace the imports automatically according to your new file structure. I think it is the exactly for what you are searching for.

Comment: I use VSCode and sometimes Atom, would love to know if there are similar features in those.